# I see that the title has been edited, but I cannot approve the edit? How can the edit be saved?

Tags: support

I have this link in my inbox:

https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/37304/revisions

But I cannot find anywhere the option to approve the edit.  Where is the edit approval button or option found?

Comment: I don't think you have to (or even get to) approve the edit. It was done by a user with high enough reputation that their edits go through without approval. The only thing you can do is, if you think the edit is not an improvement, you could roll it back. The system was just letting you know that an edit on your post had taken place - you needn't do anything.

Comment: @JonathanZ :  The interesting thing about this edit is that when I look at the article, I do not see the edit being accepted.  It just seems very strange that someone can edit a post, but there is no way for easy way that edit to get approved.  Is there someone with enough reputation who can look at the edit to see if it is possible (support)?  And as an aside, what reputation is needed on the Mathematics Stack Exchange site to approve another person's edit of the post without additional support?

Comment: Are you referring to revision 3 from 2024-03-07? That edit was already public without approval; you can confirm it by viewing [your question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/37304/89922) without logging in. This privilege is [awarded at 2000 reputation on this site](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit).

Comment: When I go to the question, I see the title "My answer was downvoted but my algebra seems perfect. Where is the error??". Do you see something different when you go to https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37304 ?